# Convert inside of a Function into String

Tags: php, string, function, email, variables

I've some web that allows mail and i tried to input the 'body' into a function on a different PHP file

```
    function body(){
        *body email on a HTML code*
    }
```

Is there any way to define the function into a string that i can define into `$body` ?

Here's what I did but nothing works

```
include '../body-email.php';
$body = echo body();
include 'PHPMailer.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

here is example of how to return a string:

```
function body(){
   return "body email on a HTML code";
}
```

For a more extensive approach to populating an email body, I recommend a templating solution such as `twig`.

For example, using an html template (just an HTML file with optional twig statements ), you can populate the PHP variables easily using twig. The template below uses an include (just another html file) which contains all the common `<head>`, `<script>` etc elements. `{{custom-message}}` is the marker, the PHP variable for the marker is simply passed to twig, which generates HTML from the template file.

```
{% include 'header.tpl' %}
<body>
    <h2>Welcome to {{siteTitle}}</h2>
    <p>
       This email tells the user something interesting. 
    </p>
    <p>
       It may include a {{custom-message}} for each user.
    </p> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: could you tell me a brief about it?

Comment: Sure, post updated.

Answer (score 0):

```
function body() {
    return '<h1>hello world</h1>';
}



include '../body-email.php';
$body = body();
include 'PHPMailer.php';
```